# Cannot acquire correct fractional values in output

Tags: c++, class, fractions

I believe I've corrected most of the program.  So far it's error-free, but I'm receiving odd values during a certain portion of execution:

My output is:

> ```
> 0/2
> 3/4
> Cannot divide by zero
> Cannot divide by zero
> 0
> 0
> Cannot divide by zero
> ____________________________________
> ```

I know that my calculations in my functions are correct, but I believe they are not receiving the saved values for the variables being passed to them.

Here is my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class fraction {
private:
    long num, den;

public:
    fraction() {}
    fraction(int n, int d) {
        num = n;
        if (d == 0) {
            cout << "Careful there, Tim..." << endl;
            exit(0);
        } else
            den = d;
    }

    void setNum(long l_num) { num = l_num; }
    void setDen(long l_den) { den = l_den; }
    long getNum() { return num; }
    long getDen() { return den; }

    long add(fraction& a, fraction& b) {
        int n = (a.getNum() * b.getDen()) + (b.getNum() * a.getDen());
        int d = a.getNum() * b.getDen();
        num = n / gcd(n, d);
        den = d / gcd(n, d);
        return num;
        return den;
    }

    long sub(fraction& a, fraction& b) {
        int n = a.getNum() * b.getDen() - b.getNum() * a.getDen();
        int d = a.getNum() * b.getDen();
        num = n / gcd(n, d);
        den = d / gcd(n, d);
    }

    long mult(fraction& a, fraction& b) {
        int n = a.getNum() * b.getNum();
        int d = a.getDen() * b.getDen();
        num = n / gcd(n, d);
        den = d / gcd(n, d);
    }

    long div(fraction& a, fraction& b) {
        int n = a.getNum() * b.getDen();
        int d = a.getDen() * b.getNum();
        num = n / gcd(n, d);
        den = d / gcd(n, d);
    }

    long inc(fraction& a) {
        int n = a.getNum() + 1;
        int d = a.getDen() + 1;
    }

    long gcd(long n, long d) {
        int remainder;
        while (d != 0) {
            remainder = n % d;
            n = d;
            d = remainder;
        }
        return n;
    }
    void print() // Display method
    {
        if (den == 1)
            cout << num << endl;
        else if (den == 0)
            cout << "Cannot divide by zero" << endl;
        else
            cout << num << "/" << den << endl;
    }
};
```

My instructor gave us strict instructions to NOT modify his given `int main()`, but here it is:

```
int main() { // define seven instances of the class fraction
    fraction f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7;
    // set values for the numerator and denominator to f1 and print
    // them
    f1.setDen(2L);
    f1.setNum(0L);
    f1.print();

    // set values for the numerator and denominator to f2 and print them
    f2.setDen(4L);
    f2.setNum(3L);
    f2.print();
    f3.add(f1, f2);
    f3.print();
    f4.sub(f1, f2);
    f4.print();
    f5.mult(f1, f2);
    f5.print();
    f6.div(f1, f2);
    f6.print();
    f7.inc(f1);
    f7.print();
}
```

I've already requested help on this program once before from SO, and I was approached with very nice people.  I've e-mailed my professor twice more, and called his office.  He has not answered // read my e-mails *read cc on open* and has not answered the voicemail I've left.

Comment: You are sure `gcd` function is OK? you have unreachable code in function `add` line `return den;`. Add some test to `gcd` function.

Comment: The integer division is no problem if `gcd` works. The only division present is `numerator / gcd` and `denominator / gcd` that is divisible if `gcd` is OK.

Comment: I've used the add function as a sort of 'test' to see if I could manipulate it to produce a good answer.  

How would I go about changing it to output right answers?

Comment: @TonisWhite What is this supposed to do? `return num; return den;`  This is in your `add` function.

Comment: I was trying to identify if return num; return den; would pass the final values to print, or at least save them so when in int main() and print was called, I would receive the right values.

I've since taken return num; and return den;

Comment: @TonisWhite You are only returning the value of `num` in that function. In C++, a function can only return a single value/object. If you want to return both values, consider creating a `struct` and return that or consider using [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: @TonisWhite - In all seriousness, guessing what C++ will do is not the way to write a program.  A function returns one value, and that is the first `return`.  The second one is ignored for the simple reason that the function has returned.  I don't see why any of your functions return anything except `void`.  The return value is useless, and most of your other functions do not return anything, even though they are declared as returning `long` (thus invoking undefined behavior).

Comment: It was just a test.  I do appreciate the constructive criticism.  In previous comments, I said I had removed the returns, both of them.

Comment: @TonisWhite You also have to change your function to return `void` (the functions that don't return anything), otherwise this all becomes a moot point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i found you problem, on your functions for add/sub when you calculated d,

```
int d = a.getNum() * b.getDen();
```

You made a mistake, for the D, you should actually do :

```
int d = a.getDen() * b.getDen();
```

From your add function you should remove the two returns

```
   long add(fraction& a, fraction& b) {
        int n = (a.getNum() * b.getDen()) + (b.getNum() * a.getDen());
        int d = a.getNum() * b.getDen();
        num = n / gcd(n, d);
        den = d / gcd(n, d);
        //return num;
        //return den;
    }
```

And on your inc function you forgot to set the num,den:

```
   long inc(fraction& a) {
        num = a.getNum() + 1;
        den = a.getDen() + 1;
    }
```

Check this out http://ideone.com/C7KgD3 to see the results

Comment: The code still invokes undefined behavior. The functions have to be changed to return type of `void`, not `long`.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe I didn't see that mistype >.<  I did remove the returns promptly after posting without anyone commenting on them, I saw the error in putting those there.

Comment: Functions are changed to void.  Same resultant, though I do appreciate you correcting me.

Comment: @TonisWhite - `Same resultant`.  What I may have done is prevent you from having an embarassing moment with your professor when he/she attempts to run your program on their computer, and strangely, it gives wrong values.  Undefined behavior means anything can happen *including* possibly work.  But also, it can mean "crash", or just plain old act weird.  By changing the function return type to `void`, you prevented this from happening.